# How to get ObjectId from different table using parse.com android

Tags: android, object, null, parse-platform

I am working on parse.com android application in which i want to get the ObjectId of my custom table "UserInfo". I have used the following line of codes but it is giving me Null value for ObjectId and can't get ObjectId from the server. Kindly show me how to get ObjectId.

```
public static ParseObject userINfo = new ParseObject("UserInfo");

String info_ = userINfo.getObjectId();// Null Value

String infow = userINfo.getString("objectId");// Null Value
```

Comment: Hi are you trying to retrieve an existing object in your Parse database or are you creating a new object?

Comment: Thanks @mussharapp for your reply. It works by using GetCallback. I was retrieving existing objects in  my Parse database.

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved my problem. It works by using CallBackMethod. Code is given below:

```
public static ParseObject user= new ParseObject("UserInfo");
user.getParseObject("info").fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ParseObject userinfo = object;
                String doctor = userinfo.getString("door");
                String allergies = userinfo.getString("algies");
                String medicalNote = userinfo.getString("mediote");
                String medications = userinfo.getString("medic");
                String medicalCondition = userinfo.getString("medicalCondition");

                docInfo.setText(doctor);
                medication.setText(medications);
                medNotes.setText(medicalNote);
                medCond.setText(medicalCondition);
                alergiesReact.setText(allergies);

                Log.i("userinfo", "" + userinfo);
            }
        });
```